# Importar biblioteca para Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel

## O que eu preciso

Preciso importar a biblioteca FPDF, modificada para o projeto.

## O que eu fiz

Código está abaixo, mas eu criei uma pasta "Libraries" dentro de "App" e coloquei a biblioteca lá(com o nome FPDF.php), coloquei no Aliasses o nome da classe e o caminho dela, além de incluir no `composer.json` o caminho da pasta lá no `classmap`. Também adicionei `namespace App\Libraries\FPDF;` no arquivo FPDF.php dentro de Libraries.

**Minha estrutura de pastas e arquivos**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

## O que aconteceu

Bom, não precisa ser um gênio para perceber: ele não está achando a classe.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**config\app.php**

```
'aliases' => [
 ...
 ...

'FPDF' => 'App\Libraries\FPDF',
```

**composer.json**

```
"autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database",
            "app/Libraries"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
```

**HomeController.php**

```
public function gerarPdf() {
        if (Input::has('numeroDocumento') && Input::has('mesReferencia') && Input::has('anoReferencia')) {
            $fpdf = new FPDF();
            $fpdf->AddPage();
            $fpdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
            $fpdf->Cell(40,10,'Hello World!');
            $fpdf->Output();
            exit;

        }
        else {
            return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'Por favor, digite todos os campos !');
        }
    }
```

Comment: Adicionou no seu controller o `use App\Libraries\FPDF\FPDF` ? No Laravel 5 a pasta app já está com autoload, não precisando usar o classmap

Comment: @gmsantos Se eu fizer assim ele dá Namespace declaration statement has to be the very first statement in the script. Preciso retirar algo ?

Comment: O namespace tem q ser a primeira coisa no seu arquivo (logo depois da tag <?php)

Comment: <?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use View, Input, App\Models\Barcode, App\Libraries\FPDF\FPDF;

    class HomeController extends Controller {

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu acredito que a classe FPDF não pertença a nenhum namespace, então, pra usar ela você teria que mapear no composer.json:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database",
        "app/Libraries/FPDF"
    ]
},
```

e nos controllers você so precisaria fazer:

```
use FPDF;
```

e usar:

```
$pdf = new FPDF();
```

documentação [FPDF Library](http://www.fpdf.org/).

Answer (score 1):

O aliasses que você está instanciando é uma classe `FPDF` dentro do namespace `App\Libraries`

no seu config.php está assim

```
'aliases' => [
'FPDF' => 'App\Libraries\FPDF',
```

Mas o que queremos é instanciar uma classe `FPDF` dentro do namespace `App\Libraries\FPDF`

Deve ficar assim

```
'aliases' => [
'FPDF' => 'App\Libraries\FPDF\FPDF',
```

Desta maneira no seu HomeController basta dar um `use FPDF` que deve funcionar